# diskutil list does not show (free space)

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, disk-space

I had an issue with a partition that refused to be deleted.

The drive is a 500 GB Samsung SSD with (previously) 2 partitions:

- Macintosh HD (apfs volume with macOS Catalina)   -- 250 GB  (disk0s1)
- Untitled (empty macOS Journaled partition)       -- 250 GB  (disk0s2)

Because the disk util app didn't work, I tried this in terminal:

```
diskutil eraseVolume 'free' 'delete' disk0s2
```

Now when I run `diskutil list` it says ([original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8Xnw.jpg)):

[image: Photo of output of diskutil list]

(I apologise for the image, I don't know how to get a text output from recovery mode)

The main issue there is that it acknowledges my drive size of 500 GB, but it doesn't show the `(free space)` it's supposed to.

When I run the `gpt -r show dev/disk0` command it returns this ([original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjUol.jpg)):

[image: Photo of output of gpt -r show dev/disk0]

Beyond this I'm not sure what to do, any help or advice is appreciated.

Comment: `diskutil` nor `gpt`  show free space.  Why is this critical at this juncture?

Comment: Well it's critical because I would like that free space available, to store stuff on.

Comment: The tool you want to use is [`df`](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/230438/119271). You said you booted into Recovery; ostensibly to repartition your drive?  Wouldn’t it be completely empty at this point?

Comment: Also try `diskutil info <device-identifier>` to get free space from`diskutil`

Comment: TKFD: I assume you are referring to the free space on the drive. Am I wrong? I think @Allan is referring to the free space on a volumes. Furthermore, the `gpt` command does shown 250 GB of free disk space between the EFI and APFS partitions.

Comment: Allan: what do you mean ostensibly? The drive partition I'm trying to remove is empty, yes. the other partition, the one I'm trying to increase in size, is not.

Comment: David Anderson: yes, I'm referring to the space on the samsung drive that is now unavailable. I found it strange that it wouldn't appear on diskutil when it does for others I've seen online. As for the GPT command, I'm honestly not sure what to do with any of that as I don't know what it all means, all I know is that indeed the bytes are there.

Comment: The ability for the `diskutil` command to show free disk space occurs only in the latest versions of macOS. I believe starting with Big Sur. If you enter the command `sw_vers`, then you will find the version of macOS you are using when entering `diskutil list` is older than Big Sur.

Comment: Note that when the `diskutil list` command does show free space, the free space is only what occurs after the EFI partition. In other words, if there is free space before the EFI partition, then the `diskutil list` command will not show this free space.